# Why can I not set a SolidColorBrush resource value from code?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, colors, resources

I have a resource defined in my xaml :

```
<core:WidgetBase xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"  x:Class="....Silverlight.LiquidityConstraintsView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:core="clr-namespace:...Silverlight;assembly=....Silverlight"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:....Silverlight"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <core:WidgetBase.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="..." />
    </core:WidgetBase.Resources>
...
```

I am trying to set it from code :

```
void _administrationClient_GetByFilterModuleSettingCompleted(object sender, GetByFilterModuleSettingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        this.Resources["..."] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
```

But I get the error :

**The method or operation is not implemented.**

stack trace :

```
   at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.set_Item(Object key, Object value)
   at ....Silverlight.LiquidityConstraintsView._administrationClient_GetByFilterModuleSettingCompleted(Object sender, GetByFilterModuleSettingCompletedEventArgs e)
   at ....Service.AdministrationServiceClient.OnGetByFilterModuleSettingCompleted(Object state)
```

It happens when I send off a request to a server to fetch me a colour, then when it returns I try and set that colour to the resource, it fails even if I try and set it as red at that point.

If it at all helps, the method in which I am setting this is an async callback method from WCF call to a server.

Comment: it should work.. i tried it at my end it works.Where exactly are you setting this value can you share some more code?

Comment: I agree, the error doesn't match with this typical action. Could we have a stacktrace?

Comment: Perhaps this is due to the fact that: `Silverlight does not support dynamic resources. All resource references to keyed resources in XAML are static.` Link on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903925(VS.95).aspx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the setter for `ResourceDictionary` in Reflector (for Silverlight), you'll see it throws a `NotImplementedException`, so this will not work in Silverlight.

You could try removing the resource and re-adding it, but that's a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 3):

"This indexer implementation specifically blocks a "set" usage. If you attempt to set a value using the indexer, an exception is thrown. You must remove and re-add to the ResourceDictionary in order to change a key-value pair."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms601221(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This operation will work as expected if you try it in a new WPF Application:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush" Color="Aqua" />
</Window.Resources>

public MainWindow()
{
    this.Resources["Brush"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    InitializeComponent(); 
}
```

Therefore, I suggest to you that your problem lies elsewhere.

UPDATE >>>

How about avoiding this problem altogether and simply using a `public` property in your `MainWindow.xaml.cs`?

In `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public SolidColorBrush Brush { get; set; }
```

Then anywhere in your application, you *should* be able to access this property like this:

```
((MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow).Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Comment: Yes I tried it in a fresh WPF application and it works, but I am using silverlight maybe it makes a difference.

Comment: Yes I could use a public property, only problem with that is I need this color available to be in an IValueConverter...